# Null returned when trying to access child object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading, entity-framework-migrations

I am in the process of migrating to EF6 from Linq To Sql, and I have the autogenerated object

```
public partial class PCU
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PCU()
    {
        this.PUs = new HashSet<PU>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FileNumberID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PartnerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PU> PUs { get; set; }
}
```

where PartnerID is the Foreign key for company

when I call:

```
var company = dc.Set<PCU>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Company;
```

I get a Null object, however if I call:

```
var company = dc.Set<PCU>().Where(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Select(x => x.Company).First();
```

It returns the company object as expected. I have both LazyLoading and ProxyCreation enabled.

I understand I could use:

```
var company = dc.Set<PCU>().Include(x => x.Company).FirstOrDefault(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Company;
```

however, as this is existing code, and I have the same problem for hundreds of different objects, this will mean massive amounts of changes. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but a recommendation. Lazy Loading can have a really big impact on the performance, because every consumer of your entities can request further entities without knowing it and this will result in many roundtrips to the database. I would recommend you to deactivate it and use either ```.Include()``` or ```.Select()``` to construct projections. Besides that, your lazy loading is not working. Please post your configuration of the context, maybe some other can help you with this information.

Comment: this is the expected behavior of lazy loading. Unless you tell the entity framework to fetch a related entity, it won't. The `FirstOrDefault` method will execute the query and when you are trying to access the Company object, it will be null. But in the second scenario, when you use company in select and execute the `First` statement, it actually tells ef to load the related data as well.
[Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: @AamirMasood This is not expected behavior. Lazy loading enables you to work without ```.Include()```.

Comment: Yes, Lazy loading enables to work without `.Include()`, but unless you actually use the navigation property in `Select` or any variant thereof, it will not load the related data .

Comment: @AamirMasood This is also not true. Take a look [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) or [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/eager-loading-lazy-loading-and-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework/).

Comment: [This](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) was my understanding as well until recently. We faced similar problem as it was not loading the related entities at all once we called the `ToList()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up, I believe the cause of the error is the name of the ForeignKey (PartnerID), and if it were named "CompanyID" it would work fine.

I have had to bite the bullet, and had to implement

```
var company = dc.Set<PCU>().Include(x => x.Company).FirstOrDefault(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Company;
```

where neccesary. There does not seem to be another workaround, except for renaming the columns in my DB (which I can't do).

Answer (score 0):

At first it indeed looks like:

`dc.Set<PCU>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Company`

is similar to:

`dc.Set<PCU>().Where(c => c.FileNumber == fileNumber).Select(x => x.Company).First()`

but in case the foreign key 'Company' is null while using 'FirstOrDefault', returning 'Company' will obviously return null.

The second case, selects a valid 'Company' FK from the result set which was created by the 'Where' condition, and returns the first one from that set, this is why the 'Where' query returns a 'Company'.

If you don't wish to alter existing code, it seems to me that the best solution for you will be to actually see why you have null foreign keys in your database in the first place.

If it's the way its supposed to be (e.g., a null 'Company' entry could exist) then you'll have to take it into account in your queries, hence changing them to return only existing 'Company' entries.

**Edit**: I take it back, I missed the 'LazyLoading enabled' part